# Плавное скрытие блока если внутри него ничего нет

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имею сайт с подгрузкой контента, но не очень нравится, что он появляется резко. Нажимаю на ссылку — и через 1 сек появляется блок. Хотелось бы, чтобы при вызове функции блок на 2 секунды скрывался, а потом появлялся.

Comment: Желательно пример или на чистом js, или на jQuery, без разницы. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: какой блок будет скрываться?

Comment: с id='BOOX'. По умолчанию он пуст, но при клике на ссылку в него загружаеться контент из файла. Вот сайт: http://world.s56.wh1.su (не реклама)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.navmenu .linked').on('click', function(){
        $('#BOOX').hide();
        $('#BOOX').fadeIn();
    })
});
```

Comment: Если блок первоначально пуст, и в него загружаю инфу, он появляется плавно, а если меняю инфу внутри него, то он опять появляется резко. Как это можно решить?

Comment: Можно попробовать CSS без всяких скриптов: #BOOX {-webkit-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out; -moz-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out; -o-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out; -ms-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out; transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;}

Comment: css не робит, а второй вариант тоже не работает. Блок конечно появляеться, но это не на что не влияет ведь при смене контента то меняеться его содержимое а не сам блок. Вот сайт: http://world.s56.wh1.su/ (не реклама)

Comment: не работает.. а что если сделать при клике на ссылку сначала скрытие блока, а потом плавное появление? При помощи wow?

Comment: Как это можно сделать? Желательно функцию, а то у меня ссылки в onclick собирают параметры а потом передают их в функцию, которая уже их перебирает и запускает другие функции.

Comment: Удалите WOW и animate.css. Просто напишите скрипт jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.navmenu .linked').on('click', function(){
        $('#BOOX').hide();
        $('#BOOX').fadeIn();
    })
});

Comment: Спасибо, это гениально, даже и не думал что можно все сделать чисто на jQuery..

Comment: Один маленький вопрос, а как увеличить время плавного появления?

Comment: $('#BOOX').fadeIn('slow'); - или slow, или цифрой от 100, например, $('#BOOX').fadeIn(500);

Answer (score 1):

Загрузить контент можно в скрытый `div`, затем показать его. Чтобы показать блок через 2 секунды применяем функцию `setTimeout(showBum, 2000);`, где `showBum` - пользовательская функция, в нашем случае показывает область с загруженным контентом, далее 2000 - 2 секунды в миллисекундах.

```js
$('#but').on('click', function(){
  $('#time').show();
  setTimeout(showBum, 2000);
});

$('#but2').on('click', function(){
  $('#time').hide();
  $('#bum').hide();
});

function showBum(){
  $('#bum').fadeIn(1000);
}
```

```css
#bum {
  font-size: 40px;
  display:none;
}
#time {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="загрузить" id="but">
<input type="button" value="сброс" id="but2">
<div id="time">Через 2 секунды загрузится.</div>
<div id="bum">Бамбалей!</div>
```

Comment: А вариант в этот код сделать плавное появление с помощью голового js или jQuery?

Comment: @W_0rld добавил `fadeIn()`.